# Database "Identity" field and auto-increment

Tags: database, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm writing my first database application and I've got an ambiguity I can't seem to find an answer for. I have an id field that is the identity set to auto-increment. My issue is trying to determine when the field is incremented. Is the field incremented when I call an instance of the object, when I call the AddObject method of the ObjectContext class, or when I call the SaveChanges method from an Entity model.

In my relational database each table has both a unique ID for that table and one that represents a group of users. After I create an instance of an object for that table I want to run a query (LINQ) that searches two tables to match two records and from one of those tables copy that group ID back to the individual user.

That or it is blatently obvious I know nothing about how relational databases work,

Comment: When your problem is solved, please mark one of the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The identity field is handled by the database. It is created by the database when the row is inserted. The generated id is read back by `SaveChanges` and the entity object is updated.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was what I had assumed but obviously thats not a methodology to work with. Guess work never end well I find. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

WHen you add a new row to the database the counter is incremented.

If you have an ambiguity, this usually means that two tables fields are the same name, and your query doesn't know which one you want. Can be solved by defning which table the column is ment for.

I don't know LINQ, so hopefully someone can give you a more direct answer.